# I am using proxy in reactjs its working on deveopment but after build proxy doesn't works how to solve it. Help Me

Tags: reactjs, api, flipkart-api

Anybody any can help me to fix this (Or) Develop any other way to complete this in Reactjs.

I am using this on package.json

```json
"proxy": "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net",
```

And App.js Code is

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Menutry extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fdata: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var config = {
      headers: {
        "Fk-Affiliate-Id": "onlinesho41",
        "Fk-Affiliate-Token": "bd6298b80c164655bf12a15d405cf09f",
      },
    };
    axios
      .get("/affiliate/api/onlinesho41.json", config)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data.apiGroups.affiliate.apiListings);
        this.setState({ fdata: data.data.apiGroups.affiliate.apiListings });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }
  render() {
    let Repltxt;
    return (
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(this.state.fdata).map((apiCat, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {
              (Repltxt = this.state.fdata[apiCat].availableVariants[
                "v1.1.0"
              ].resourceName.replace(/_/gi, " "))
            }
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Menutry;
```

After the build proxy not but current window url display infront of api url. Error

[image: Console error image here]